# Angular - How can I access an outside app element?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular 4.3.1.

Suppose I have this `index.html` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="." />
     ...
     ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>
    loading...
  </my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

An App "domain" is starting from the `<my-app>` elements and its inner elements.

But what if I want to access the `<head>` element and set one of it's attribute to some value ?

Something like :

```
  <head [myVal]="myObjectVal">
```

Sure I can access the `DOM` via `Document.querySelector()`  , But I wonder if there's a better way ( Angular way maybe?)

**Question:**

Suppose I have a service (@Injectable) and it has an object , how can I set `<head [myVal]="myObjectVal">` in the *Angular way* ?

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3xHfml5g7sO9TNRhgY3w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular doesn't support binding to elements outside the root element.

You can use plain TS/JS like

```
document.querySelector('head')...
```

There is also the [Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) service that allows to set meta tags.

Comment: And the [Title](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title) service to change the title :)

Comment: Okay but if I want to apply SEO to the Head element with keywords , will the crawler see the keywords or won't it? I'm saying that because I fill it via Ajax request so viewsource doesn't have data

Comment: I don't know about that. If crawlers find meta tags when you set them in JavaScript, they should find it when you set from Angular. This shouldn't be Angular related.